# Parsing CSV data and updating a dictionary and creating a polyline

Tags: arcpy, csv, cursor, dictionary

I am a little stuck on my code.  I am new to Python and am learning as I go, but have usually been able to figure it out till now.  The code was working up till I put the dictionary part in and now this is where its failing.  When I run the program, it only goes through once and doesn't appear to be storing the data.  I have found people in the discussions have had the same problem, but they never said what helped them resolve the issue.  Below is a breakdown of the objective of the program:

The rhinos in the spreadsheet appear in no guaranteed order, and not all the rhinos appear at the beginning of the spreadsheet. As I parse each line, I must determine which rhino the reading belongs to and update that rhino's polyline track accordingly. I am not allowed to sort the Rhino column in Excel before I export to the CSV file. My script must be "smart" enough to work with an unsorted spreadsheet in the order that the records appear.

I do not immediately know how many rhinos are in the file or even what their names are. Although I could visually comb the spreadsheet for this information and hard-code each rhino's name, your script is required to handle all the rhino names programmatically. The idea is that I should be able to run this script on a different file, possibly containing more rhinos, without having to make many manual adjustments.

Sample Data:

```
Observer,X,Y,Rhino,Comments
Ben,26.99391,-19.10447,Bo,
Ben,27.00071,-19.1089,Tulip,Bathing
Ben,26.9919,-19.10511,Bo,
Ben,27.00071,-19.1059,Tulip,
Ben,26.96809,-19.09578,Patches,
Ben,26.97808,-19.11016,Dinky,
Ben,26.99213,-19.10395,Bo,
Ben,27.00083,-19.10326,Tulip,
```

I am lost and confused....

```
#Import a csv file into ArcMap and plot the points for each Rhino
import arcpy
import csv

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\GEOG485\\Lesson4\\Project4"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

targetFolder = "C:\\GEOG485\\Lesson4\\Project4"
rhinoShape = "C:\\GEOG485\\Lesson4\\Project4\\Rhino.shp"
rhinoFile = "C:\\GEOG485\\Lesson4\\Project4\\RhinoObservations.csv"
spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(rhinoShape).spatialReference

try:
    #Open CSV file and read the headers

    trackPoints = open(rhinoFile, "r")
    textLine = trackPoints.readline()
    headerLine = textLine.strip("\n")    
    pairList = headerLine.split(",")
    print pairList
    polylineArray = arcpy.Array()
    #Get index for header fields
    xIndex = pairList.index("X")
    yIndex = pairList.index("Y")
    rhinoIndex = pairList.index("Rhino")
    print rhinoIndex

    #Created an empty dictionary
    dictionaryRhinoTracks = {}

    for line in trackPoints.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        splitLine = line.split(",")
        print splitLine
        #Created variable for needed field items based on index location
        pointX = splitLine[xIndex]
        pointY = splitLine[yIndex]
        rhinoName = splitLine[rhinoIndex]

        #Create a point object

        currentPoint.x = pointX
        currentPoint.y = pointY
        currentPoint = arcpy.Point(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y)
        print currentPoint

        #Check if the dictionary does not contain name
        if rhinoName not in dictionaryRhinoTracks:
            rhinoTrackArray = polylineArray.Add(currentPoint)
            #Add the point object to the Array
            dictionaryRhinoTracks[rhinoName].Add(currentPoint)


    cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(rhinoShape, ['SHAPE@'])
    cursor.insertRow([polyline])

    for rhinoName in dictionaryRhinoTracks:   
        row.Shape = dictionaryRhinoTracks[rhinoName]
        row.Rhino_Name = rhinoName
        cursor.InsertRow(row)

except:
    print ("error again")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Using a huge `try` block is often a good way to hide errors from debugging attempts. I suggest adding more print statements, so you can follow the program logic, then report the debug output and error message in this question.

Comment: As @Vince suggests, lose the `try...except` and please post the stack trace along with your question to make it easier for people to help. Also, because this is a homework question be aware that people will likely help with the specific problem, but won't answer the whole question for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `try:...except:` when debugging.  Don't use silent and [overly broad exception handling](https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/) ever.

Some comments:

1. You're not using the `csv` module. You import it, then never use it, instead you manually read and parse the file as text.
2. `arcpy.Array` doesn't have an `Add` method, it has an `add` method - python is case-sensitive
3. You're mixing the old [`arcpy.InsertCursor`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/insertcursor.htm) and [`arcpy.da.InsertCursor`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) syntax.  Avoid `arcpy.InsertCursor`, use `arcpy.da.InsertCursor`.
4. `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` doesn't have an `InsertRow` method, it has an `insertRow` method - python is case-sensitive
5. You use a `polyline` variable which isn't defined anywhere
6. You don't create an `arcpy.Polyline` anywhere
7. You try to use `currentPoint` before you actually define it
8. Your X and Y values are strings, they need to be floats.

You would have seen error messages about 2 - 8 if you had not used `try:` `except:` and hidden them.

So... even though I think this is a homework question... You've had a good try at answering it yourself, so here is how I would do it.

First, I'd use the CSV module and a [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to make life easy.  Then I'd use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) so I don't have to check whether a Rhino is already in the dict.  Don't forget to check out how to use an `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` and consider using `with` statements so your open files and Insert/UpdateCursors get cleaned up automatically.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import arcpy

target_folder = 'etc...'
rhino_shape = 'etc...'
rhino_file = 'etc...'

rhino_tracks = defaultdict(arcpy.Array)

with open(rhino_file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        point = arcpy.Point(float(row['X']), float(row['Y']))
        rhino_tracks[row['Rhino']].add(point)

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(rhino_shape, ['SHAPE@', 'Rhino']) as rows:  # Assume a shapefile with a 'Rhino` text field
    for rhino, array in rhino_tracks.items():
        polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)
        rows.insertRow([polyline, rhino])
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and help.  This is a homework question that has had me stumped for a few days now.  Now I can't add a text field into the shapefile in advance, so would I create the field in the program?  That way when it runs it will put "Rhino" into the shapefile?

Comment: If the shapefile exists, you can check for a "Rhino" field with `if "RHINO" in [f.name.upper() for f in arcpy.Describe(rhino_shape).fields]:` and use `arcpy.AddField_management` to add a Rhino field if not.

Comment: I think this is a great answer highlighting classic "school boy" errors. Your 8 point list of the problems really show that one must be methodical in developing code, understand data types and understand the nuisances of the chosen language (in this case Python).